# getting 1500 statuses via fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get all status updates of a some facebook users with their permission.The code I am using is

```
//gets statusid, message and uid of the user
function get_status_message($access_token){
    // Run fql query
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+message+,+status_id+,+uid+FROM+status+WHERE+uid=me()AND+time+>=946684800'
    . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

  //display results of fql query
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r("query results:");
  print_r($fql_query_obj);
  echo '</pre>';
  return $fql_query_obj;
}
```

I have set the time to see all statuses after 01/01/2000  but I am getting only 100 status messages. I tried to change the time limit to be between 01/01/2009 and 01/01/2010 . Again , I am getting the messages only if they fall  within the last 100 messages. Is there any workaround for this . I read multiuple posts on lincreasing the limit and I have tried it but it does not work